# How to globally handle "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter x"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know the best way to globally handle "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter x" error.

I realize that I can always set parameters as `nullable type` and test them using their `HasValue` property.

I'd rather find a more generic approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a global approach, but if your actions' parameters have sensible defaults, why not try just making them optional parameters?  For example :

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, string name = "user") { ... }
```